# using mail.to.add to send to specific user based on text field

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, vba, email

I am attempting to send an email from a button click in my vb code.  The code works fine; when clicking the button, it will send an email to the specified email address in mail.to.add.  How can I pass a variable to this so the email will be sent to a user based on an email in a text field rather than one specified in the vb code?

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim mail As New MailMessage
    mail.Subject = "Membership"
    mail.To.Add("********")
    mail.From = New MailAddress("**********")

    mail.Body = "Congratulations!  You have been approved as a member!"



    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("Smtp.gmail.com")
    smtp.EnableSsl = True
    smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("*******", "**********")
    smtp.Port = "587"
    smtp.Send(mail)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a textbox to the .aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="EmailTextBox" runat="server" />
```

and in code aspx.cs use

```
mail.To.Add(EmailTextBox.Text)
```